How do I save a multi-page tiff image to memory stream?
I'm running into problems trying to save a multi-page tiff image to a MemoryStream.  I have seen a lot of material on how to save a multi-page tiff but all the examples save the image to a file and not to a MemoryStream.
When I save to file it works as expected (giving me the three pages in the tiff image on the drive).  However, when I try to save to a MemoryStream and then take that MemoryStream and save to a file I only end up with the first page.
Here is what I have right now and it's only giving me the first page in the end.
public void Test()
{
    // Add 3 image files to the cache list
    List<Image> imageCache = new List<Image>();
    imageCache.Add(Image.FromFile(@"c:\test\testInput1.tif"));
    imageCache.Add(Image.FromFile(@"c:\test\testInput2.tif"));
    imageCache.Add(Image.FromFile(@"c:\test\testInput3.tif"));

    // Get the tiff image codec
    ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(c => c.MimeType == "image/tiff").First();
    if (codec == null)
        throw new Exception("Tiff codec not found.");

    // Create compression encoder parameter
    EncoderParameter compressionParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);

    // Create first page frame parameter
    EncoderParameter firstFrameParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

    // Create additional pages frame parameter
    EncoderParameter additionalFramesParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

    // Create color depth parameter
    EncoderParameter colorDepthParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, (long)1);

    // Create flush parameter
    EncoderParameter flushParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);

    // Create last frame parameter
    EncoderParameter lastPageParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.LastFrame);

    // Create first page encoder parameters
    EncoderParameters firstFrameParams = new EncoderParameters(2)
    {
        Param = new EncoderParameter[]
        {
            compressionParam,
            firstFrameParam,
        }
    };

    // Create additional pages encoder parameters
    EncoderParameters additionalFrameParams = new EncoderParameters(2)
    {
        Param = new EncoderParameter[]
        {
            compressionParam,
            additionalFramesParam,
        }
    };

    // Create save to file encoder parameters
    EncoderParameters saveToFileParams = new EncoderParameters(2)
    {
        Param = new EncoderParameter[]
        {
            compressionParam,
            colorDepthParam,
        }
    };

    // Create flush encoder parameters
    EncoderParameters flushParams = new EncoderParameters(1)
    {
        Param = new EncoderParameter[]
        {
                flushParam,
                lastPageParam,
        }
    };

    // Save the bitmap to memory as tiff
    using (MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _imageCache[0].Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);

        // Put Tiff into another Image object
        using (Image tiff = Image.FromStream(byteStream))
        {
            // Save to file - Uncomment next line for working solution
            //tiff.Save(@"c:\test\testOutput.tif", codec, firstFrameParams);

            // Save to a memory stream - Comment out next three lines for working solution
            using (MemoryStream tiffStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                tiff.Save(tiffStream, codec, firstFrameParams);

                // For subsequent pages, prepare encoders
                for (int page = 1; page < _imageCache.Count; page++)
                    tiff.SaveAdd(_imageCache[page], additionalFrameParams);

                // Finally flush the file
                tiff.SaveAdd(flushParams);

                // Save the image in memory to a file - Comment out next three lines for working solution
                using (Image tiffOutput = Image.FromStream(tiffStream))
                    tiffOutput.Save(@"c:\test\testOutput.tif", codec, saveToFileParams);
            }
        }
    }
}

Worth noting that the image object tiffOutput when created from stream does NOT contain the 3 frames expected but only the 1 (first) page.  It's like the Image.SaveAdd method does not work on memory streams even though it says it does.

Better to amend your question than comment on it.

Thanks @LeeTaylor...  I was going to do that and then went with a comment because I felt I was adding too many edits every time I thought of something new.  Started feeling like my post was an animated gif.

Can you please provide [mre]? Something which I can run and where I don't need to spend hours on fixing missing usings. Thank you. I don't know what _imageCache is.

I did not add a bunch of optimization and using blocks because I have had issues in the past where objects (specifically image related objects) getting consumed and causing other issues that caused a bunch of extra time to debug.  Once I had a working solution I was going to add all my using blocks back.  This was just for debugging and adding using blocks in this situation is just good code practice.  It will not change the results of what I'm trying to accomplish with the question.  It will at worst create a memory leak for the small image objects in the short moment of testing.

@ThomasWeller I can add more code if it's really needed but I was concerned of causing other issues with using statements.  _imageCache is an array of Image objects.  Sorry about that.

@ThomasWeller I think I got you what you were after, sorry again for the sloppy code before.  Was in a debug mindset.

Shouldn't you simply reset the stream before reading it?

@PoulBak I'm not sure what you mean.  The issue is I have 3 image files, and if I put them together using .Save for the first page and .SaveAdd for all the other pages, I only end up with page one.  Are you saying that at the start of the for loop I should call something like tiffStream.Position = 0?

Seems I was wrong, the stream is automatically reset: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=net-8.0
